# c++ / scope of struct

Tags: c++, scope

In following code, I think that structure stSameNameButDifferent is local scope definition and so no problem for it.  But I got error in run-time.
(error : process crash)

Can you explain what's wrong with that code?

test_function.h

```
#ifndef TEST_FUNC_H_
#define TEST_FUNC_H_
void test_a();
void test_b();

#endif
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "test_function.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char** argv)
{
        cout << "testing for struct scope" << endl;
        test_a();
        test_b();
        return 0;
}
```

test_a.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <cstdint>
#include <list>
#include "test_function.h"

struct stSameNameButDifferent
{
        uint32_t nPlayCode;
        uint32_t nGameID;
        std::string sGameName;
};

void test_a()
{
        std::list<stSameNameButDifferent> lstSt;
        for(int i=0; i<10; ++i)
        {
                stSameNameButDifferent st;
                st.nPlayCode = i;
                st.nGameID = 100+i;
                std::ostringstream osBuf;
                osBuf << "Game_" << i;
                st.sGameName = osBuf.str();
                lstSt.push_back(st);
        }
        for(auto &st : lstSt)
        {
                std::cout << st.nPlayCode << ", " << st.nGameID << ", " << st.sGameName << std::endl;
        }
}
```

test_b.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <cstdint>
#include <list>
#include "test_function.h"

struct stSameNameButDifferent
{
        uint32_t nPlayCode;
        uint32_t nGameID;
        float    fDiscountRate;
        std::string sGameName;
};

void test_b()
{
        std::list<stSameNameButDifferent> lstSt;
        for(int i=0; i<10; ++i)
        {
                stSameNameButDifferent st;
                st.nPlayCode = i;
                st.nGameID = 1000+i;
                st.fDiscountRate = (float)i/100;
                std::ostringstream osBuf;
                osBuf << "Game_" << i;
                st.sGameName = osBuf.str();
                lstSt.push_back(st);
        }
        for(auto &st : lstSt)
        {
                std::cout << st.nPlayCode << ", " << st.nGameID << ", " << st.sGameName << std::endl;
        }
}
```

Comment: Congratulation, you have met your first non-trivial sized program, now you know why you shouldn't use `using namespace std;` and would want define your own namespace.

Comment: _"I got error"_ WHAT ERROR?!

Comment: @Surt: This has nothing to do with `using namespace std`.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, process crashed.

Comment: @heon: And what did your debugger say was the cause? _"I got error"_ and _"process crashed"_ are **insufficient** problem descriptions. They're not even full sentences. Come on...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid clashes of the same `struct` names in multiple translation units, you have to put them in an unnamed namespace like so:

```
namespace {
    struct stSameNameButDifferent {
        uint32_t nPlayCode;
        uint32_t nGameID;
        std::string sGameName;
    };
}
```

This will make `stSameNameButDifferent` only seen privately in the corresponding translation unit (`.cpp` file).

Otherwise the linker will resolve the symbol with the first one found, hence the errors you see at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

you have defined `stSameNameButDifferent` in global scope, so compiler cannot see and analyze both definitions to same `struct` and it only take the first one it meet and that's why you are getting an error.

You can use two different namespaces for `test_a` and `test_b`, so you will not get any error.

Comment: _"compiler can see two definitions to same struct"_ You are mistaken.